# How we can find Highest time spend by user on tag by taking data from three tables mention below in sql query

Tags: mysql

We have one product wise time spend table such as

```
--------------------------------------------------
ID| Timespent | Userid | productID           |
--------------------------------------------------
1 | 12333     | 420     | 223
2 | 3647      | 424     | 423
3 | 333       | 424     | 823
4 | 1333      | 654     | 283
--------------------------------------------------
```

Above table have multiple entries in it

We have another table which has a product and tag mapping

```
--------------------------------------------------
product_id      | tag_id |        
--------------------------------------------------
1               | 4352     
823             | 43   
823             | 654    
423             | 4352     
--------------------------------------------------
```

We have another table which has the tag name

```
--------------------------------------------------
tag            | tag_name |        
--------------------------------------------------
1               |  NEWS     
823             | Sports   
223             | cricket    
423             | football     
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the sum of time spent according to tag and users wise for example

user id should be distinct and total time spent will be the sum of timespent

```
--------------------------------------------------
user_id | tag_name | total_time_spend
--------------------------------------------------
823     | football | 324237462
722     | cricket  | 324237462
839     | new      | 324237462
923     | USA news | 324237462
23      | MODI     | 324237462
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: @pawansgi92 . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: I remove the extra tags

Answer (score 1):

Use join and corelated sub-query

```
    select t.* from ( 
    Select  p.userid, tn.name,sum(p.timespent) as total
    From product p join tagmapping tm
     on p.productid=tm.product_id
     Join tagname tn on tm.tag_id=tn.tag
     Group by p.userid,tn.name
             ) t where total=
                   select max(total) from 
                   (
                    Select  p.userid, tn.name,sum(p.timespent) as total
                    From product p join tagmapping tm
                    on p.productid=tm.product_id
                   Join tagname tn on tm.tag_id=tn.tag
                   Group by p.userid,tn.name
                    ) a where a.userid=t.userid
```

Comment: it will give a unique group of user id and name ... So it will repeat user_id